# Laravel 5 Eloquent Realtionship has one through

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following database structure

```
products            quesionnaires           questionnaire_results
--------            --------------          ----------------------
id                  id                      id
questionnaire_id                            questionnaire_id
                                            product_id
```

A Questionnaire can be used for multiple products, and store results for each product, apart, in questionnaire_results table.

A product can have only one questionnaire and only one result of its questionnaire.

I need a way to get from Product Model the result of its Questionnaire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have a `QuestionnaireResult` model then there is no straightforward Eloquent relationship for this, as all of the default relationships rely on the existence of an Eloquent model. However, there is a fairly clean way to accomplish this by treating it as a [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between `Product` and `Questionnaire` and treating `questionnaire_results` as your pivot table (even thought you really *know* that a product will only ever belong to one Questionnaire).

Product Model:

```
public function questionnaire() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Questionnaire', 'questionnaire_results');
}
```

Questionnaire Model:

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'questionnaire_results');
}
```

As this relation will return a collection, you need to either access the first array with `[0]` or use the `first()` method.

```
$product->questionnaire()->first();
```

However, if you *do* have a `QuestionnaireResult` model then you have a very straightforward [One to One](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relationship with no need to go through another model. You have some questionnaire results that belong to a product, while a product can only have one set of questionnaire results (according to your post info).

Product Model:

```
public function questionnaireResult() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\QuestionnaireResult');
}
```

Questionnaire Result Model:

```
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Product Model
public function quesionnaire() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Quesionnaire");
}

// Quesionnaire Model
public function questionnaire_result() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Questionnaire_result");
}
```

`$product->quesionnaire->questionnaire_result`